# Read string within double quotes in perl

Tags: perl

I have a file which contains lines like this:

```
"pin1" Inpin; "pin2" outpin; "pin3" inoutPin;

some other string "pin4" inpin
```

I want to store just pin1, pin2, pin3, pin4 (basically words within double quotes). Can someone please help..? Basically read one line at a time and grab the word within double quotes only. I tried to split a line by ";" but it doesn't work since ";" may not be present in all lines.

thanks!

Comment: **Try writing something yourself** and then if it doesn't work, **show us specifically what you did** so we can help you along. **You start it, and then we help. We don't write it for you.** Show us the actual code that you've tried, and then describe what happened and what's not right, and then we can help you from there. Chances are you'll get pretty close to the answer if you just try it yourself first.

Comment: Describe carefully what you want to match. Then turn that into a regular expression.

Answer (score 0):

```
join ', ' $str =~ /"([^"]*)"/g
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code:

```
    my $string = '"pin1" Inpin; "pin2" outpin; "pin3" inoutPin;`';


my @array;


while ( $string =~ /\"(.+?)\"/ )
{
    put (array, $1.),
    $string =~ s/\"$1\"//;
}
```